# irreductibility of induced representation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $\rho: G \longrightarrow \text{GL}_{\mathbb{C}}(V)$ and $\alpha: G \longrightarrow \text{GL}_{\mathbb{C}}(W)$ be two irreducible representations of a finite gr0up $G$.

Is true that the induced representation $G \longrightarrow \text{GL}_{\mathbb{C}}\big(\text{Hom}(V,W)\big)$ is always irreducible?

I have been trying to prove it by contradiction but I am lost. Any help?

Comment: I assume by Hom you mean the space of all linear maps? In any case, this will rarely be irreducible.

Comment: What is the degree of this representation? What happens if you take $\rho=\alpha$ to be of maximal degree for an irreducible of $G$?

Comment: For finite-dimensional vector spaces $V$ and $W$, $\text{Hom}_\mathbb{C}(V,W)$ is naturally isomorphic to $V^*\underset{\mathbb{C}}\otimes W$.  You were asking whether tensor products of two irreducible representations of a finite group are necessarily irreducible.  Use the answer there to answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by $Hom(V,W)$ you understand the set of all linear maps $V\to W$ (well it doesn't make much sense for it to mean anything else). Then the answer is "no". If $\rho$ is of maximal dimension with $\dim_{\mathbb{C}} V>1$ and $\alpha=\rho$ then

$$\dim_{\mathbb{C}} Hom(V,V)=(\dim_{\mathbb{C}} V)^2>\dim_{\mathbb{C}} V$$

is just too big and thus it has to be reducible.

Such an example is given by $S_3$ which has $3$ irreducible representations over $\mathbb{C}$: two of dimension $1$ and one of (maximal) dimension $2$. You can [read more about it here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_symmetric_group).

Answer (score 1):

A nice direct counter-example is that for $V=W$, the space $Hom(V,V)$ always contains the one-dimensional invariant subspace spanned by the identity map.